# How to display the variable value in the summary report

Tags: jmeter

For each  sampler result I have a variable value which I want to show it in the summary report as a test result. How to write this value in the jtl file and show it in the summary report?

Answer (score 3):

You can write the variable into a file using `sample_variables` property.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=foo
   ```

   replace `foo` with your actual variable name
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. That's it, an extra column will be added to the .jtl results file holding the `foo` variable value for each [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

With regards to displaying it in the summary report, this is not something you can do out of the box, however you can plot the variable value as a chart in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). If this is something you're interested in - add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=Foo values
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=Foo values
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=foo
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Foo value :
```

again, replace `foo` with your actual JMeter Variable name

References:

- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I am getting null in the jtl file. I replaced foo with my actual variable name in the  user.properties file.